# DoCmd.RunSQL SELECT STATEMENT

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

```
select g.mailbox 
from voorwerp v inner join bod b
ON v.voorwerpnummer = b.voorwerp
inner join gebruiker g
ON g.gebruikersnaam = b.gebruiker
where v.verkoper = Me.gebruikersnaam
AND v.veiling_gesloten = 'false'
```

Hello!,

Look at the code above. I need to use this code in an acces VBA code. In this code I am using 3 different tables. Me.gebruikersnaam is a field in the acces application. 
I hope you guys know a way so I can use this code in an Acces VBA code!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need a string:

```
SQL = "select g.mailbox " & _
    "from ((voorwerp v inner join bod b " & _
    "ON v.voorwerpnummer = b.voorwerp) " & _
    "inner join gebruiker g " & _
    "ON g.gebruikersnaam = b.gebruiker) " & _
    "where v.verkoper = '" & Me.gebruikersnaam & "' " & _
    "AND v.veiling_gesloten = 'false'"
```

Comment: Thank you! It almost works! I only get error code 2295. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Perhaps your last field is a _Boolean_. Then:  `"AND v.veiling_gesloten = False"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select g.mailbox 
from ((voorwerp v inner join bod b
ON v.voorwerpnummer = b.voorwerp)
inner join gebruiker g
ON g.gebruikersnaam = b.gebruiker)
where v.verkoper = Me.gebruikersnaam
AND v.veiling_gesloten = 'false'
```

Greetings Group 3 I-Project